# Angular 7 How to use given API references in typescript

Tags: angular

Hi Im new to angular nature and trying to customize the look and feel of following library.

https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider (it has given API references bellow in this page)

in this [demo](https://sanjayv.github.io/ng-image-slider/) the developer has shown customizing the slider, however there isnt a single example on how to do this in the template or the component typescript.

[image]

I tried many ways , one for example

```
@Input() 
public imageSize= {width: 30, height: 30}; but none of them worked
```

Say I need to change the image sizes to `30 x 30 px`. it can be done in the demo using given input boxes.

I need to do this within the code. Please help

Comment: I belive you can see how the author has built the demo on this link: https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider/tree/master/src/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is stored under https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider/tree/master/projects/ng-image-slider.
The example https://sanjayv.github.io/ng-image-slider/ is stored under https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider/tree/master/src.

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-image-slider *ngIf="showSlider" #nav
  [images]="imageObject"
  [infinite]="sliderInfinite"
  [imagePopup]="sliderImagePopup"
  [showArrow]="sliderArrowShow"
  [imageSize]="{width: sliderImageWidth, height: sliderImageHeight}"
  [autoSlide]="sliderAutoSlide ? 1 : 0"
  [slideImage]="+sliderSlideImage"
  [animationSpeed]="sliderAnimationSpeed"
  (imageClick)="imageOnClick($event)"
  (arrowClick)="arrowOnClick($event)"
  (lightboxArrowClick)="lightboxArrowClick($event)">
</ng-image-slider>

<td>
  <div class="size-div">
    <span class="input-title">Width</span>
    <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
      <input type="number" max="500" [value]="sliderImageWidth" [(ngModel)]="sliderImageWidth" />
      <i>px</i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="size-div">
    <span class="input-title">Height</span>
    <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
      <input type="number" max="500" [value]="sliderImageHeight" [(ngModel)]="sliderImageHeight" />
      <i>px</i>
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
    sliderImageWidth: Number = 300;
    sliderImageHeight: Number = 225;
}
```